# Simple Docker container to show matplotlib plots

Tags: python, linux, docker

I have a simple Docker file in which I am pulling a miniconda image and installing matplotlib on it:

```
# Comment
FROM conda/miniconda3

RUN pip install matplotlib
```

I build the image using a `docker build` command:

```
docker build -f DockerFile . -t test:test
```

I then generate a container and access the shell within it:

```
docker run -it test:test bash
```

I then start the python interpreter and try to check the backend used in matplotlib:

```
root@0d7701938257:/# python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.rcParams['backend']
'agg'
```

Since I want to be able to `.show()` my plots I try to set `TkAgg` as my backend, but this throws an error:

```
>>> matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1155, in use
    plt.switch_backend(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 259, in switch_backend
    class backend_mod(matplotlib.backend_bases._Backend):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 260, in backend_mod
    locals().update(vars(importlib.import_module(backend_name)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import _backend_tk
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Apparently my Python is not configured for `Tk` although the `tkinter` library seems to be there. I'm not sure how to fix this. What is the libX11.so.6 file? Why does this file fail to open? How can I make a simple custom container which is capable of `.show()`ing my plots?

### Edit

I was able to fix the above error by running:

`apt-get update`
`apt-get install libx11-dev`

`matplotlib` now appears to be able to `.use('TkAgg')`, but then `pyplot` fails to load:

```
root@0d7701938257:/# python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2319, in <module>
    switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 270, in switch_backend
    newbackend, required_framework, current_framework))
ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running
```

Why does it fail to load the backend?

Comment: Try `apt-get install libx11-dev`

Comment: Not all python binaries bundle all their required dependencies. Some require calling out to resources on the underlying system. In this case it's saying you don't have libx11 installed.

Comment: I get an error when I run that...: `E: Unable to locate package libx11-dev`

Comment: need to `apt-get update` first

Comment: You should also make sure you do cleanup in the same step to not cause bloat to the docker layers. I usually do something like: `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libx11-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

Comment: @flakes, your suggestion helps, but it does not completely solve the problem. Could you take a look at the edit to my original question?

Comment: tkinter is a GUI tool. You need to properly configure docker to be able to display the content. This is why you have the x11 dependency in the first place. It's really going to depend on your os settings/ hardware outside of docker, so it's hard to post a definitive answer for everyone. This page has a few suggestions: http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/GUI

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [ros](http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/GUI) tutorial,
with debian:

```sh
docker pull debian:latest
docker run -it \
    --user=0 \
    --env="DISPLAY" \
    --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" \
    --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" \
    --name debian debian:latest /bin/bash
exit

docker ps -a
export containerID=$(docker ps -l -q)
echo "$containerID"
xhost +local:`docker inspect --format='{{ .Config.Hostname }}' $containerID`
docker start $containerID
docker ps

docker exec -it debian /bin/bash
apt-get update
yes | apt-get install libx11-dev
yes | apt-get install tk
yes | apt-get install python3
yes | apt-get install python3-tk
yes | apt-get install python3-matplotlib

python3 <<EOF
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
exit()
EOF

exit
docker stop $containerID
docker rm $containerID
docker ps -a
```